# How to send as many inputs as we have to the program using bash script?

Tags: bash

Running an arithmetic parser using a bash script inside the bash I am reading all the inputs using : $@ because every time I can have different number of inputs. 
When I send 1+1 it can parse it fine but when I send (1+1) I get this error:

```
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1+1'
```

How can I change it to be able to read parenthesis as well?

Note: the parser works fine even with parenthesis.

Comment: Why displaying your non-bash code, since it is a bash issue?

Comment: The only thing in my bash is $@ for reading input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote your arguments when calling the bash script:

```
bash myscript.sh "(1+1)"
```

or escape the special characters:

```
bash myscript.sh \(1+1\)
```

Comment: you are a life saver! but is there anyway I can handle it inside the bash script? that would be more convenient!

Comment: No. You either quote or escape the special characters.

Comment: Thanks I will send my input with the double quotes then